# Javascript How to check if object is null when I'm getting a string

Tags: javascript

I have a list of fields called "files".
This list contains `<a>` elements, but not all have the attribute "data-docid". I'm trying to check one by one if each element have that attribute with this sentence:

```
if (files[i].getAttribute('data-docid') !== null){}
```

When the element NOT contains the attribute, it works fine but when it has the attribute, I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Where is the mistake? I need to differentiate between them

Comment: you're checking for null ... perhaps it's `undefined`

Comment: @JaromandaX I'll check this but getAttribute() returns null, not undefined

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be here. Please write a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: try to get length if == 0?

Comment: Please don't do useless minor edits. This prevents other users to bring real improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for `file.getAttribute('data-docid') !== null` works perfectly fine. You should consider to check the `files` variable.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(file => {
  if(file.getAttribute('data-docid') !== null) {
    console.log(`Attribute of "${file.innerHTML}" is "${file.getAttribute('data-docid')}"`);
  } else {
    console.warn(`No Attribute found for`, file.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-docid="Amazing, looks fresh">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `null` and `undefined` are falsy values. Perhaps getAttribute returns undefined. You could try simply:

```
if (files[i].getAttribute('data-docid')) { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

From your example, is better if u use this way for checking your files

if files.hasOwnProperty(i) and files[i].hasOwnProperty('data-docid')